# Where to start with Keyboard interrupt Handler

Tags: interrupt-handling, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm getting started with a program in MARS MIPS that will allow the user to input something in the MMIO input window in the form of "x+y=" and get "x+y=z". However, I just don't really know where to start. I have the basics setup, but I need to write an entire interrupt handler.

I'm using MARS MIPS< and have enabled the interrupt bit, but that's about all I've figured out.

```
.text

main:
    #Turn on the interupt enable bit
    lui $t0, Oxffff
    lw $t1, 0($t0)
    ori $t0, $t1, 0x0002
    sw $t1, 0($t0)



.data
expBuffer: .space 60
expBuff: .word 0

.ktext 0x80000180
#Store all used registers

#Recover all used registers

.kdata
#Registers
```